# Extreme sexual urges, can masturbation be allowed

Tags: masturbation

Salam, I would like to ask if masturbation is actually haram, because in the Quran 23.5-7- Allah says "And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts, from illegal sexual acts). Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame. But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors." According to me, this verse tells us that we should not show our private parts to anyone except our spouses and slave-girls. If it does mean that we cannot show it to anyone except them, it means even we cannot even see our own private parts, which almost everyone does. Also, to say something is haram it has to be explicitly mentioned in the Quran. All the Hadith like the one where the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) said that whoever masturbates, is cursed, has a weak authenticity. I have not done masturbation for almost a month, which is making my urges run wild, please help.

Comment: The majority of scholars considered masturbation haram. But There are a few scholars who allowed it if it is an absolute last resort and the only thing between one and zina. But however it doesn't mean that you can watch pornography. Watch this fatwa for more info

 https://youtu.be/1DtNKU25ejY

Comment: Brother Yusha, I said I quit watching pornography, thank you

Comment: I have extreme sexual urges currently which I am unable to control, I can't control it in any other way, please help.

Comment: As I said that majority scholars considered masturbation as haram. And you can try to control it by fasting, and lowering your gaze and etc. But if you can't really control it, and you have tried all of that. And you fear that you might commit zina fornication then according to some scholars, masturbation can be done

Answer (score 0):

Masturbation is haram in Islam. The verse clearly says that you can have sexual pleasure from your wives and slaves. It doesn't mean you can't see your private part that's not haram. You have to guard your private part from others except wives and slaves. You can't have self pleasure from it. Most scholars said it is haram.
Jazakallah Khairan